# Show $e^{f(x)} = 4x$ has a unique solution using Banach fixed point theorem

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

I am stuck trying to prove the following:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ be a contractive map. Use the Banach contraction principle to show that the equation
>   $$e^{f(x)} = 4x$$
>   has a unique solution.

In order to use the principle, I need to restrict the domain to $[0,1]$. Then there is some unique $\overline{x} \in [0,1]$ such that $f(\overline{x}) = \overline{x}$.

The problem I am having is trying to derive the right hand side, since
$$e^{f(\overline{x})} = e^\overline{x}$$
does not seem to help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a fixed point of $e^{f(x)}/4$, what's a Lipschitz constant for that in terms of the Lipschitz constant for $f$? (Hint: you can use the derivative of the exponential itself even if $f$ isn't differentiable.)

Comment: From what I understand, I need find some M such that $(1 / 4)d(e^{f(x)},e^{f(y}) \leq M d(f(x),f(y)) \leq M*K d(x,y)$ for the Lipschitz constant $K$ of $f$. I don't quite understand what you mean by using the derivative of the exponential even if $f$ is not differentiable

Comment: @AndreuPayne The point is that you can take $M$ to be a Lipschitz constant for $e^y$ where $y$ is restricted to the range of $f$. You can get that Lipschitz constant as a bound on $\left | \frac{d}{dy} e^y \right |$ on this range.

Comment: @EricWofsey Just out of curiosity, were you the downvoter? If so can you please revert your vote now?

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove that $e^f(x)/4$ is contractive.

Hint: use the mean value theorem for the exponential function and look at the range for $f$.